# If you feel remorse and sincerely repent can Allah forgive third party

Tags: allah, sin, tawba, forgiveness

I know I asked this question before but if you sincerely repent feel remorse and any kind of third party and you promise Allah never to return to this can he forgive you because some people say Allah cannot forgive third party

Comment: What are you referring to as the third party? Do you mean will Allah forgive you if you do bad to others ?? 
Please elaborate more. Thanks.

Comment: Yes any kind of bad and you feel remorse but you feel like if you ask for forgiveness from them you will make things worse

Comment: Can you sincerely repent and will Allah forgive you

Answer (score 0):

Assalam o Allaikum brother.

Try to confront those people with all your heart and pray to Allah that they forgive you. Because no matter what we do, Allah doesn't forgive us person until or unless that person forgives us whom we wronged.

Once Prophet Muhammad (SAWW) was asked by the Sahabah "Do you know who a bankrupt person is?" They said the bankrupt among us is the person who does not have any wealth. Prophet Muhammad (SAWW) said, “**The bankrupt person is someone who comes on the day of judgement with many rewards, prayer, fasting, Zakat, but he had accused a person falsely, he abused another, cursed a third, taken the money of somebody else, spilt the blood of someone else, so he ends up giving them from his good deeds and if he runs out of good deeds and he didn’t pay them back, then they start giving him some of their sins and he ends up going to hellfire.**" - Sahih Muslim

If there is a sin committed by us then it's between us and Allah and Allah can forgive us, but if there is a sin committed between us and someone else, then that has to be sorted out between the two.

> Allah says in the Quran, "**The recompense for an evil is an evil like
> thereof; but whoever forgives and makes reconciliation, his reward is
> with Allah. Verily, He likes not the oppressors.**" [42:40]

If you have done this out of being oblivious to the fact that it is a sin, then Inshallah, Allah will pardon you. The fact that you have changed and are attempting to fix things that you had done in the past shows that Allah has blessed you with the goodness of character.

The best way is to talk to them directly and speak to them from your heart and ask for forgiveness. May Allah softens their hearts and they shall understand that you indeed have changed. But if you still think that confronting them will make things worse then the best tool you have is dua. Try to make dua for her daily without skipping a day and it will connect you to her in a beautiful, spiritual way. Allah will bless both of you, and you never know, what the power of dua will bring your way!